# Are Latin causative verb ending -eō and Old Slavic -ити from verbs eō and ити ("to go")?

Tags: latin, slavic-languages

Are Latin causative verb ending -eō and Old Slavic -ити from verbs eō and ити ("to go")?

Comment: I'm not familiar with "causative" -eō. Do you mean verbs like caleō, torpeō, stupeō?

Comment: @Draconis You are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I wouldn't call Latin -eō verbs like *caleō* "be hot" and *torpeō* "be numb" causative; they're stative, expressing a state of being. The causatives would be *calefaciō* "make hot" and *torpefaciō* "make numb".

Second, the Latin ones at least aren't related to *eō* "go". The suffix comes from PIE **-éh₁-yeti*, while the verb comes from **h₁ey-* "go". I believe the Slavic suffix **-ěti* and verb **jьti* come from the same places as the Latin ones.

Comment: The Latin second conjugation combines PIE *\*-éh₁yeti* statives with *\*-éyeti* causatives (/iteratives). Your examples are statives, but e.g. *moneo*, *torreo*, *noceo*, *compleo* are (fairly) transparently causative in origin. It's definitely too much to call -eō a causative verb ending, though, [and presumably Wiktionary is to blame here, again](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Italic/-e%C5%8D).

Comment: @Cairnarvon True, but in the comments OP said they meant the caleō type. (I wouldn't necessarily call the second type of -eō verb causative in Latin, even if it is a causative formation in PIE (and PIt).)